# Maven install a modified jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jar

I have a jar file which causes JBoss deployment to fail. And I found the solution by modifying the tld file in this jar. After that, I mvn install this jar to another folder, (P.S, the old jar is still in the maven local repo just with a different folder). Then in my pom.xml file, i use this to import my modified jar file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mycustom</groupId>
            <artifactId>springmodules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Then in the code, I cannot reference this jar at all. I have tried mycustom.springmodules.xxx or the old reference,none of this works.. Could anyone tell me how I can reference this jar.
P.S The jar file is spring-modules-validation-0.8
or in maven, you can import this like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
    <version>0.8a</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn clean install -o` once and try accessing things in jar.